# Sorting a list by business logic ids

Tags: java, sorting

Im surprised I havent come accross this before in java. I know I can solve this using decorator objects but I was wondering if anyone can think of a more succinct way of doing this.

I have a method that take a list of ids. Inside the method I do some manipulation, retrieve objects from db etc etc. At the end of the method the order of the resultant list is not guaranteed. I want to order it by ID on the ids that are being passed into the method. These IDs may not be numerically ordered.

Fro example

```
List<MyObject> get (List<Integer> ids) {
   //get from db etc and do manipluation
   //MyObject contains an id which corresponds to one of the ids passed in
   //order the list according to the order of the ids parameter
}
```

ids could contain 1,2,3 in that order. Or 4,7,3,1,7  It is the order that the ids have been passed in whcih si the order I want the VOs to be returned in.

I could decorate the VOs and add another parameter to allow some natural ordering but this seems a lot of code for something quite simple. Like I said at the beginning Im surprised after all these years not to have come accross this already.

Any ideas for a nice succinct pattern for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: since you are getting the data from DB why dont you sort it when you retrieve it from database?

Comment: good point, I forgot I could sort using custom ids field in the db retrieval. Will hve to check JPA here out of interest. However I still think there can be problems when I manipulate the VOs. Ideally I'd like to do it at the end of the manipulation

Comment: if you are using a list. you can override equals and hashcode method then list.sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about implementing a Comparator which compares two MyObjects based on the list that you get as input and then sort the MyObject objects using this comparator?

```
public class MyObjectComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {

List<Integer> list;

MyObjectComparator(List<Integer> list)
{
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
    return Integer.compare(list.indexOf(o1.getId()), list.indexOf(o2.getId()));
}
```

}

I haven't tested this code and am also not sure if this is efficient way of doing.

Comment: perfect thanks. A nice elegant solution which is what I was after :)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it by executing a query for every individual ID.
If you iterate the list with an iterator and for every ID you do the DB query and you add it to the result list, in my opinion the returned list contains the objects in the same order as the IDs in the argument List.

Maybe you want to write only one query and then I would look into modifying your sql query...

Answer (score 0):

Example of sorted result:

```
private List<MyObject> get(List<Integer> ids)
{
  HashMap<Integer, MyObject> calculated;
  for (Integer id : ids)
  {
    // do fetch work here
    MyObject object = doWork(id);
    calculated.put(id, object);
  }

  // sorted result
  LinkedList<Integer> sortedIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  sortedIds.addAll(ids);
  Collections.sort(sortedIds);

  LinkedList<MyObject> sortedResult = new LinkedList<MyObject>();
  for (Integer id : ids)
  {
    sortedResult.add(calculated.get(id));
  }
  return sortedResult;
}
```